# Conditional logic in xsd

Tags: xsd, conditional-statements

I have a xml with following tags

```
<root>
  <A>xxx </A>
  <B>xxx </B>
  <C>xxx </C>
</root>
```

The data type for A is integer and possible values are 1 or 2. I want to use xsd to put following restrictions:

If A=1, then tag B is present,
If A=2, then tag C is present.

Is there a neat way to realize this? Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The neatest thing to do here would be to change the design, since the A element is clearly providing no information at all.  Just let root contain either a B or a C.

If you really really want to explore the bad living that is possible when you violate the rule "Don't Repeat Yourself" and introduce unnecessary redundancies into your XML, then your options are Schematron assertion, RNG, and XSD 1.1 assertions.

Comment: Thank you! I am making configuration files in xml format, and xsd is the specification for the config files. A, B, C are parameters that should be exposed in xsd, but they have certain logical relationships like described above. I am wondering whether we could contain these logic relationships in xsd or not. It seems hard to achieve this, then, what is the most reasonable solution?